# Kotlin find all hardcoded strings in code using Android Studio

Tags: kotlin

(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) and type `Hardcoded Strings`: only find the hardcoded strings in the `.java` files and not find strings in `.kt` files

Answer (score 0):

Ah, well actually there's an update. Kotlin IDE does understand org.jetbrains.annotations.PropertyKey 11, but it does not always work. I have had problems if the bundle contains more than one language.

Example:

```
fun message(@PropertyKey(resourceBundle = "Messages") id: String) =
        ResourceBundle.getBundle("Messages").getString(sid) ?: "###$id###"
```

For more visit:https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#src